# C compiler cannot create executables Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, compilation

I'm trying to install CUnit lib in my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS computer. I've installed it in a Ubuntu 11.04 without problems, but when I tried to install on 10.04 I got this trace:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/home/cpcaserver5/Área de Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2/missing: Unknown `--run' option
Try `/home/cpcaserver5/Área de Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: `missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
---------- Disabling debug mode compilation.
++++++++++ Enabling automated(XML) mode compilation
++++++++++ Enabling basic mode compilation
++++++++++ Enabling console mode compilation
---------- Disabling curses mode compilation
---------- Disabling examples mode compilation
---------- Disabling test mode compilation
---------- Disabling memtrace functionality at compile time
---------- Disabling use of deprecated v1.1 names
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/cpcaserver5/Área de Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have tried a lot of libs and gcc versions, so I think that the problem is in Ubuntu, but where or why, I've no idea!

Relevant part of the log file:

```
configure:3399: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3421: gcc  -DRELEASE=@RELEASE@ -Wall -W -pedantic -Wshadow -ansi -I/home/cpcaserver5/Área de Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2/CUnit/Headers   -L/home/cpcaserver5/Área de Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2/CUnit/Sources conftest.c  >&5
gcc: de: No such file or directory
gcc: Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2/CUnit/Headers: No such file or directory
gcc: de: No such file or directory
gcc: Trabalho/CUnit-2.1-2/CUnit/Sources: No such file or directory
configure:3425: $? = 1
configure:3463: result: no
```

Full config.log >> http://pastebin.com/SrWfar1Z

I can compile C files just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a quoting problem somewhere, and the fact that the directory you installed `CUnit` to contains spaces (and non-ASCII chars) is messing things up.

While it might be possible to make this work, I strongly suggest you change the installation directory to a path that does not contain any spaces at all, and stick to plain ASCII7 characters (no accents, llama, tilde or otherwise).
You'll run into lots of scripting problems if your paths are "unusual". If you want horizontal spacing, use an underscore (`_`).

Comment: +1: Well spotted; I should have seen it too.  I used to have (rather briefly) a directory '`External Source Repositories`' but I now have a directory '`External-Source-Repositories`' for exactly this reason.

Comment: Well, this question just got me the Legendary badge, so thanks for asking it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Output from `./configure` is notoriously unhelpful, except for one line:

```
See `config.log' for more details
```

That's where the *real* error messages are.